# DataTables после перехода на другую страницу перестаёт работать кнопка

Tags: html, jquery, datatable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#popup_table').DataTable();
    jQuery('#basic_table').DataTable();

    jQuery("[data-id-backorder]").bind('click', function(){
        var data = {
            action : 'add_exception',
            product_id : jQuery(this).attr('data-id'),
        };

        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data,function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });

    jQuery("[data-del-id-backorder]").bind('click', function(){
        var data = {
            action : 'del_exception',
            product_id : jQuery(this).attr('data-del-id'),
        };

        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data,function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });

    });
});
```

Есть вот такой кусок кода который при нажатии а кнопку инициирует действия ajax. Всем известно, что DataTables имеет свою встроенную постраничную навигацию, и вот пока ты находишься на первой страничке, всё прекрасно работает, но когда переходишь на вторую и далее, при нажатии на кнопку, не происходит ничего. В логах тоже никаких ошибок.

Вот ещё кусок html + php кода

```
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-id-backorder="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo __('Add'); ?></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach($exception as $exp): ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $exp->product_id; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo WC_Helper_Sell::get_product_name($exp->product_id); ?></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-del-id-backorder="<?php echo $exp->product_id; ?>"><?php echo __('Delete'); ?></a></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде назначение обработчиков события `click` воздействует только на элементы с атрибутом `[data-id-backorder]` уже существующие на странице. Делегирование (через родителя) будет вызывать этот обработчик для элементов, которые уже есть на странице, и для элементов, которые появятся позднее.

Замените

```
jQuery("[data-id-backorder]").bind('click', function(){
```

на

```
jQuery(body).on('click', "[data-id-backorder]", function(){
```

и

```
jQuery("[data-del-id-backorder]").bind('click', function(){
```

на

```
jQuery(body).on('click', "[data-del-id-backorder]", function(){
```

Comment: Заработало.. Только в чём отличия, не понял особо

Comment: @LevBazdyrev Добавил объяснение.